# Find vector $x$ satisfying $x = a + b x^\top A x$ for known $a, b, A$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

I need to solve the following equation for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (either exactly or using numerical mehods)
$$
x = a + b x^\top A x
$$
where $a, b \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are known and $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

> Is there either a closed-form solution or an efficient optimization/numerical method that can be used to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried a simple Newton iteration?

Comment: @KBS You're right. I suppose the gradient of $f(x) = -x + a + bx^\top A x$ would be $\nabla_x f(x) = - I + 2bx^\top A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, you must have $x=a+\lambda b$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, and substituting that you get the quadratic equation $\lambda=p+2q\lambda+r\lambda^2$ where $p=a^\top A a$, $q=a^\top Ab=b^\top Aa$ and $r=b^\top A b$. You can then solve the quadratic. The case where $a$ and $b$ are linearly dependent is even simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am not sure I follow how you get the quadratic equation, maybe this is a stupid question.. Or rather, how do you know $x = a+\lambda b$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter $x = a + b x^\top A x$ expresses $x$ as some linear combination of $a$ and $b$, with the coefficient of $a$ being equal to $1$. We just conveniently "forget" the connection between $x$ and the coefficient of $b$ for the time being, and make that coefficient a completely new variable.

Comment: How can I choose between the two solutions? It seems that the one with the minus is the correct one but I wouldn't know how to explain it

Comment: @Euler_Salter They should both work. I might be missing something, but at the moment I can't see a place where we do anything that could introduce extra solutions.